# Center vertically multiple TextViews in LinearLayout

Tags: java, android, textview, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I am trying to center vertically the 4 `TextViews` in the `LinearLayout` in the below code and screenshot.  I know how to center just one of the `TextViews` vertically in the `LinearLayout` but I want all 4 to be center vertically so the same distance is above and below the top and bottom `TextViews`.

XML

```
<RelativeLayout  >

    <TextView />

    <LinearLayout  > 

        <TextView/>

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />

        <TextView />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: you mean you wants to design the screen just like that image?

Comment: android:layout_gravity="center_vertically"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to add this attribute to all `textviews` :

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

and set your `Linearlayout` with

```
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Comment: Got my desired output.  Thank you.